# Grails domain and @Canonical

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I was using `@ToString` and `@EqualsAndHashCode` in my Grails domain classes. I found out about `@Canonical` and decided to use it instead. To my surprise I now get an error:

*Unable to compile class xxx due to hash collision in constructors @ line -1, column -1.
General error during class generation: `java.util.NoSuchElementException`*

```
*java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1113)*
```

I thought this could be an issue with the old compiled classes so I deleted the target directory and tried again. Same issue.

Will `@Canonical` work with Grails domain classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8205

> 17/Jan/14 4:43 AM
>   The compiler will now generate an error if a domain class is marked with @Canonical.

Comment: Great thanks. I saw this jira  but I missed the part where Graeme said "It has been decided that @Canonical should not be supported on domain classes"